# xmonad: default size for a floating window

Tags: haskell, xmonad

To have a window placed on the floating layer as soon as it appears, one can use the `doFloat` function from `ManageHooks`. In addition there are some additional functions, like `doCenterFloat` for instance, that are provided by `ManageHelpers`.

But is there any way to specify a specific size for a window?

Right now I have an application and it just takes the whole window space. I'd like to specify a more comfortable size.

`ManageHelpers` does have a function called `doRectFloat` which takes a `RationalRect`. In the [description for `doRectFloat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Hooks-ManageHelpers.html#v:doRectFloat) it states the following:

> The rectangle to float the window in. 0 to 1; x, y, w, h.

But I don't know how to use this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `ManageHelpers` does have a function called `doRectFloat` [...] But I don't know how to use this.

The type of `doRectFloat` is...

```
doRectFloat :: RationalRect -> ManageHook
```

... so you need to pass it a [`RationalRect`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.13/docs/XMonad-StackSet.html#t:RationalRect) (following the links in the docs usually helps in figuring out such things):

```
doRectFloat (RationalRect (1 % 4) (1 % 4) (1 % 2) (1 % 2))
```

This should produce a centered rectangle with half of the full width and length. `%` is used to build `Rational` (a type for exact fractions) values. To use it, you will need to add [`import Data.Ratio`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Ratio.html) to the imports at the top of your `xmonad.hs` file.

Comment: Ah yes. At first it did make the window a floating window, but the size and position were not adjusted. As it turned out, this had to do with `placeHook simpleSmart` from `XMonad.Hooks.Place`. As soon as I disabled that one, your solution worked. Thank you.

Comment: For the curious reader - I am using the `composeOne` ManageHook composer, rather than the more frequently used `composeAll`. The former stops as soon as there is a match. This explains why it didn't originally work, and instead of disabling `placeHook simpleSmart`, I have now placed it after the list of individual windows I want to be floating.